# django-autocomplete-light with gm2m in modals bootstrap: the select not showing in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-autocomplete-light

i I'm trying to get autocomplete-light with Gm2m , But autocomplete.GM2MQuerySetSequenceField doesn't shows all choices.

View.py

```
class RessourceAutocompleteView(Select2QuerySetSequenceView):

def get_queryset(self):
        employees = Employees.objects.all()
        freecontracts = Frecontract.objects.filter(IS_ACTIVE=True)
        freeagencies = Freagencies.objects.filter(IS_ACTIVE=True)
        freelancers = Freelancers.objects.filter(IS_ACTIVE=True)

        if self.q:
            employees = Employees.objects.filter(EMP_FIRST_NAME__icontains=self.q)
            freecontracts = Frecontract.objects.filter(FIRST_NAME__icontains=self.q,
                                                       IS_ACTIVE=True)
            freeagencies = Freagencies.objects.filter(AG_NAME__icontains=self.q,
                                                      IS_ACTIVE=True)
            freelancers = Freelancers.objects.filter(FRE_FIRST_NAME__icontains=self.q,
                                                     IS_ACTIVE=True)
            #

        # Aggregate querysets
        qs = QuerySetSequence(employees, freecontracts, freeagencies, freelancers)
        # qs = QuerySetSequence(employees)

        if self.q:
            # This would apply the filter on all the querysets
            qs = qs.filter(Q(EMP_FIRST_NAME__icontains=self.q)|
                           Q(FIRST_NAME__icontains=self.q)|
                           Q(AG_NAME__icontains=self.q) |
                           Q(FRE_FIRST_NAME__icontains=self.q
                          ))

        # This will limit each queryset so that they show an equal number
        # of results.
        qs = self.mixup_querysets(qs)

        return qs
```

Forms.py :

```
class QAMForm(autocomplete.FutureModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(QAMForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in iter(self.fields):
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
            'class': 'form-control'
        })

TRANSLATOR = autocomplete.GM2MQuerySetSequenceField(
    queryset=autocomplete.QuerySetSequence(
        Employees.objects.all(),
        Frecontract.objects.all(),
        Freagencies.objects.all(),
        Freelancers.objects.all(),
    ),
    required=False,
    label=_("Traducteur(s)"),
    widget=autocomplete.QuerySetSequenceSelect2Multiple(
        'qm:ressource-autocomplete'),
)

PROOFREADER = autocomplete.GM2MQuerySetSequenceField(
    queryset=autocomplete.QuerySetSequence(
     # all models 
        Employees.objects.all(),
        Frecontract.objects.all(),
        Freagencies.objects.all(),
        Freelancers.objects.all(),
    ),
    required=False,
    label=_("Relecteur(s)"),
    widget=autocomplete.QuerySetSequenceSelect2Multiple(
        'qm:ressource-autocomplete'),
)
PM = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Employees.objects.filter(TYPE_RESOURCE__TYPE__in = ('PMJ', 'PMS')),
                                    required=False, label=_("PM(s)"),)
# QA = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employees.objects.filter(TYPE_RESOURCE__TYPE__in=('PMJ', 'PMS')),
#                            required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Feedback
    fields = ['PM']
```

Models.py:

```
class Feedback(models.Model):
#the fields
TRANSLATOR = GM2MField()
PROOFREADER = GM2MField()
PM = models.CharField(max_length=250,  blank=True, null=True)
```

I apply it under modals bootstrap in the first click to display the modals that contains the form it does not display the select with choices just after the second click.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just eliminate in View.py :

```
qs = self.mixup_querysets(qs)
```

Because the function mixup_querysets will limit each queryset.